# How to check whether folder exist in external Storage in Android?

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-permissions, android-external-storage, internal-storage

```
String fldr= "Main";
```

I need to find whether there is a folder called fldr in anywhere in the directory.

This will return the Directory of External storage

```
String SDpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

If there is a folder similar to fldr I need to get its directory and check whether its writable.. How to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

do this way,

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Main");
if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
    // do something here
}

/**
   * @return True if the external storage is available.
   * False otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean checkAvailable() {

    // Retrieving the external storage state
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    // Check if available
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)
        || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * @return True if the external storage is writable.
   * False otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean checkWritable() {

    // Retrieving the external storage state
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    // Check if writable
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in this case we don't know "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Main" exists. It may be a something like this "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"folder1"+ "/Main"" 
then how to find whether main is exists ?

Comment: you just pass only directory name(folder name).

Comment: when use  File directory = new File("DCIM");  it says it does not exists

Comment: but when use File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM"); it says it exists.. so how can I get correct results only using "DCIM"